# Assign elements on page with values from a JSON file

Tags: html, ajax, json

I have a multilanguage web application and I want to store all the text in a JSON file and load in each text for each element on each page. For example:

```
$("h1.text1").append(data[language]['startpage'][0]['text1']);
```

Tjis will depending on the language show a different text in h1.text1.

At the moment I'm giving each element a unique class for example h1.text1 and in the JSON calling them by that class eg. text: "Title". Then I assign them with JQuery like the above example. Just wondering if there is a better way to do this? Because I'm going to have lots of lines of code to assign in each element in each page?

Comment: Personally I would do it, recursively based on the amount of contents within `startpage`. That way you have information updating one after another and not concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would probably do this is by using data tags:

```
<div data-translate="myTranslateIdHere"></div>
```

Then you could have your json data include the data-translate id. This would then be simple in javascript. You could iterate over your json array, and use the data-translate id to find the element, and set the text of that element. Something like the below:

```
$(myJSON).each(function(key, val) {
    $("[data-translate='" + val["translateId"] + "']").text(val["translateValue"]);
});
```

You then just need to update your JSON to have the correct structure with a translateId mapping to a translateValue. Obviously you would have to also rework the above JavaScript to fit your JSON, it was just meant as a quick example of the idea.

Comment: hi, that would be a solution but I have to use XHTML and I don't think I can use data-tags with XHTML.

Comment: If you have to use XHTML, you could possibly do the same with the id tag of the element, though that has disadvantages (you wouldn't be able to have the same text in two places without defining the translation twice).